How to create subgroups based on group relationship criteria
Context:
I have a dataframe of individual people grouped by household, which includes relationship parameters for each individual describing their relationship to every other individual in the household.
Goal: I am trying to create sub-groups within households according to tax-units. Individuals are considered a single tax-unit if they are (1) a spouse or (2) a dependent child. A dependent child is defined as a child under 18 or a child who is under 23 and a student.
There may be a single tax-unit or multiple tax-units within a given household. Other married couples, or individuals in each household who are not dependent children, form separate tax-units.
Example Dataframe:
   household     name age student                r01         r02          r03               r04          r05
1          1     john  60       0               <NA>      spouse       parent            parent       parent
2          1     mary  56       0             spouse        <NA>       parent            parent       parent
3          1    fiona  25       0              child       child         <NA>           sibling      sibling
4          1      tim  20       1              child       child      sibling              <NA>      sibling
5          1     nora  16       0              child       child      sibling           sibling         <NA>
6          2 terrence  58       0               <NA>      spouse child-in-law step-child-in-law       parent
7          2  siobhan  57       0             spouse        <NA>        child        step-child       parent
8          2      jim  90       0      parent-in-law      parent         <NA>            spouse grand-parent
9          2    maire  87       0 step-parent-in-law step-parent       spouse              <NA>        other
10         2     eoin  21       1              child       child  grand-child             other         <NA>
11         3   ronald  50       0               <NA>        <NA>         <NA>              <NA>         <NA>

Code to reproduce:
df <- data.frame(household = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), 3),
           name = c("john", "mary", "fiona", "tim", "nora", "terrence", "siobhan", "jim", "maire", "eoin", "ronald"),
           age = c(60, 56, 25, 20, 16, 58, 57, 90, 87, 21, 50),
           student = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
           r01 = c(NA, "spouse", rep("child",3), NA, "spouse", "parent-in-law", "step-parent-in-law", "child", NA),
           r02 = c("spouse", NA, rep("child", 3), "spouse", NA, "parent", "step-parent", "child", NA),
           r03 = c(rep("parent",2), NA, rep("sibling", 2), "child-in-law", "child", NA, "spouse", "grand-child", NA),
           r04 = c(rep("parent",2), "sibling", NA, "sibling", "step-child-in-law", "step-child", "spouse", NA, "other", NA),
           r05 = c(rep("parent", 2), rep("sibling",2), NA, rep("parent", 2), "grand-parent", "other", NA, NA))


Approach:
To start I created variables to list family member order, and to identify a dependent child.
df <- df %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  mutate(fam_mem = row_number(),
         dep_child = ifelse(age < 18 | (age < 23 & student == 1), 1, 0))

My next step was to then identify parents of dependent children, using match however this is where I am getting stuck, as match will tell me if they are a parent, but I cannot link it to dependence status.
After this I hoped sort by dependence status and use lag to create a new household variable name, which groups into tax-units, e.g. 1a, 2a, 2b, 3a.
Desired Output
   household name       age student r01                r02         r03          r04               r05          fam_mem dep_child household_tax_unit
       <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>              <chr>       <chr>        <chr>             <chr>          <int>     <dbl> <chr>             
 1         1 john        60       0 NA                 spouse      parent       parent            parent             1         0 1a                
 2         1 mary        56       0 spouse             NA          parent       parent            parent             2         0 1a                
 3         1 fiona       25       0 child              child       NA           sibling           sibling            3         0 1b                
 4         1 tim         20       1 child              child       sibling      NA                sibling            4         1 1a                
 5         1 nora        16       0 child              child       sibling      sibling           NA                 5         1 1a                
 6         2 terrence    58       0 NA                 spouse      child-in-law step-child-in-law parent             1         0 2a                
 7         2 siobhan     57       0 spouse             NA          child        step-child        parent             2         0 2a                
 8         2 jim         90       0 parent-in-law      parent      NA           spouse            grand-parent       3         0 2b                
 9         2 maire       87       0 step-parent-in-law step-parent spouse       NA                other              4         0 2b                
10         2 eoin        21       1 child              child       grand-child  other             NA                 5         1 2a                
11         3 ronald      50       0 NA                 NA          NA           NA                NA                 1         0 3a  

John and Mary share a tax unit with their dependent children Tim and Nora, while Fiona is given her own tax-unit as she is not a dependent child.
Terrence and Siobbhan are married and share a tax unit with their dependent child Eoin, while Jim and Maire share a different tax-unit as their child/step-child is not a dependent and they are married.
Ronald lives alone therefore is a single tax-unit.

please show the desired output

thanks, I have added desired output above

The memb function creates an incidence matrix mm from the r columns and dep_child.  The line with the logical condition marked ## is the key line and the following line ensures that mm is symmetric. Now given mm form an igraph graph g.  Finally create a membership vector as the output of the memb function.
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

memb <- function(dep_child, r) {
  m <- as.matrix(r)[, 1:nrow(r), drop = FALSE]
  m[is.na(m)] <- ""
  mm <- m == "spouse" | (m == "child" & dep_child)  ##
  mm <- mm | t(mm)
  g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mm, mode = "undirected")
  components(g)$membership
}

df %>%
  mutate(unit = row_number(),
         dep_child = +(age < 18 | (age < 23 & student == 1)),
         memb = memb(dep_child, pick(starts_with("r"))), 
         memb = paste0(household, letters[memb]), .by = household)

giving
   household     name age student                r01         r02          r03
1          1     john  60       0               <NA>      spouse       parent
2          1     mary  56       0             spouse        <NA>       parent
3          1    fiona  25       0              child       child         <NA>
4          1      tim  20       1              child       child      sibling
5          1     nora  16       0              child       child      sibling
6          2 terrence  58       0               <NA>      spouse child-in-law
7          2  siobhan  57       0             spouse        <NA>        child
8          2      jim  90       0      parent-in-law      parent         <NA>
9          2    maire  87       0 step-parent-in-law step-parent       spouse
10         2     eoin  21       1              child       child  grand-child
11         3   ronald  50       0               <NA>        <NA>         <NA>
                 r04          r05 unit dep_child memb
1             parent       parent    1         0   1a
2             parent       parent    2         0   1a
3            sibling      sibling    3         0   1b
4               <NA>      sibling    4         1   1a
5            sibling         <NA>    5         1   1a
6  step-child-in-law       parent    1         0   2a
7         step-child       parent    2         0   2a
8             spouse grand-parent    3         0   2b
9               <NA>        other    4         0   2b
10             other         <NA>    5         1   2a
11              <NA>         <NA>    1         0   3a


Perhaps just consider student also?  For example, change the mutate line to : memb = memb(if_else(age<23 & student==1, 17,age), pick(starts_with("r"))),

Have updated to fix errors and to make output values correspond to newly posted desired output.

Here's an approach using igraph to define the groups. Note that this will not catch all cases (e.g. if a parent appears later than the 5th person in a household it may not capture the parent-child relationships correctly.) But it works for your sample data.
# create test data
df <- read.table(text = "household     name age student                r01         r02          r03               r04          r05
1          1     john  60       0               <NA>      spouse       parent            parent       parent
2          1     mary  56       0             spouse        <NA>       parent            parent       parent
3          1    fiona  25       0              child       child         <NA>           sibling      sibling
4          1      tim  20       1              child       child      sibling              <NA>      sibling
5          1     nora  16       0              child       child      sibling           sibling         <NA>
6          2 terrence  58       0               <NA>      spouse child-in-law step-child-in-law       parent
7          2  siobhan  57       0             spouse        <NA>        child        step-child       parent
8          2      jim  90       0      parent-in-law      parent         <NA>            spouse grand-parent
9          2    maire  87       0 step-parent-in-law step-parent       spouse              <NA>        other
10         2     eoin  21       1              child       child  grand-child             other         <NA>
11         3   ronald  50       0               <NA>        <NA>         <NA>              <NA>         <NA>
")

library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

# add a person identifier to the data
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(person = row_number(), .by = household)

# pivot wider to define relationships between person and r_person
# filter to keep only required relationships
df_pivot <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("r"), names_to = "r_person")%>%
  mutate(person = paste0(household, "-", person)) %>%
  mutate(r_person = as.numeric(substring(r_person, 2), .by = household)) %>%
  mutate(r_person = paste0(household, "-", r_person)) %>%
  filter(r_person != person & (value %in% c("spouse") | (value == "child" & (age <= 23 | student == 1)))) 

# function to define groups using igraph. The result is a data.frame which can be
# joined to the original data
make_groups <- function(data) {
  # create a graph from the pivoted data.frame
  rel_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(select(data, r_person, person)) 
  
  # The membership component is a named vector of group identifier for each
  # connected group
  group_vector <- components(rel_graph)$membership
  
  # return a data frame with household, person (as per orignal data frame) along
  # with group_id
  data %>%
    mutate(
      group_id = group_vector[person]
    ) %>%
    distinct(person, group_id) %>%
    separate_wider_delim(person, names = c("household", "person"), delim = "-") %>%
    mutate(person = as.integer(person), household = as.integer(household))
  
}

# use this function to create the lookup with the group_id variable
lookup_groups <- make_groups(df_pivot)

# join this with the original data, then re-calculate group_id for the ungrouped
# members of each household, and recode to household_id + letter format
want <- df %>%
  left_join(lookup_groups, by = c("household", "person")) %>%
  mutate(
    group_id = if_else(is.na(group_id), 1000000000 + row_number(), group_id),
    group_id = paste0(household, letters[as.factor(group_id)]),
    .by = household
  )

want
#>    household     name age student                r01         r02          r03
#> 1          1     john  60       0               <NA>      spouse       parent
#> 2          1     mary  56       0             spouse        <NA>       parent
#> 3          1    fiona  25       0              child       child         <NA>
#> 4          1      tim  20       1              child       child      sibling
#> 5          1     nora  16       0              child       child      sibling
#> 6          2 terrence  58       0               <NA>      spouse child-in-law
#> 7          2  siobhan  57       0             spouse        <NA>        child
#> 8          2      jim  90       0      parent-in-law      parent         <NA>
#> 9          2    maire  87       0 step-parent-in-law step-parent       spouse
#> 10         2     eoin  21       1              child       child  grand-child
#> 11         3   ronald  50       0               <NA>        <NA>         <NA>
#>                  r04          r05 person group_id
#> 1             parent       parent      1       1a
#> 2             parent       parent      2       1a
#> 3            sibling      sibling      3       1b
#> 4               <NA>      sibling      4       1a
#> 5            sibling         <NA>      5       1a
#> 6  step-child-in-law       parent      1       2a
#> 7         step-child       parent      2       2a
#> 8             spouse grand-parent      3       2b
#> 9               <NA>        other      4       2b
#> 10             other         <NA>      5       2a
#> 11              <NA>         <NA>      1       3a

Created on 2024-07-12 with reprex v2.1.0
